# How to use ionic 2 RC 4 native Network

Tags: angular, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am following the ionic 2 docs on how to use Network which is a cordova plugin network information

```
 import { Network } from 'ionic-native';

 // watch network for a disconnect

let disconnectSubscription = Network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
 console.log('network was disconnected :-(');
 });

// stop disconnect watch

    disconnectSubscription.unsubscribe();



  let connectSubscription = Network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
       console.log('network connected!'); 

     setTimeout(() => {
       if (Network.type === 'wifi') {
        console.log('we got a wifi connection, woohoo!');
       }
     }, 3000);
   });

 // stop connect watch
 connectSubscription.unsubscribe();
```

How to use this in context of retrieving data from a server-side (e.g. when subscribing service.ts) so it keeps watching whether there is connection or not! can some provide a piece of code on how to utilize this! I'm not sure what is stored in `disconnectSubscription` so that I can set a condition statement to log the result (this is supposedly when I'm watching the network when retrieving data) and when should I `unsubscribe` the watch!

Also, there is an error on `if (Network.type === 'wifi')` 
 property `type` does not exist of typeof `Network`

Comment: Ok I solved the part on how to watch for the connection disconnect....but the error `Network.type` still persists

Comment: According to the docs [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/network/) there is method called type(). maybe a mistake in the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using ionic-native v2.2.12 or higher, there was a breaking change in this version on which they introduced Network.type.

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/releases/tag/v2.2.12

Comment: How to update it!!  I ran "npm install ionic-native --save" again... the version thats being installed is ionic-native@2.2.11 , I also tried `Network.connection` there is no error but it does not log anything, it logs an empty Object.....`Object {}`

Comment: Hey @DavidBracoly, I had this same issue, just put the latest release in your package.json mine is "ionic-native": "2.2.14",